# A question on Hausdorff measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

This question is part of a homework assignment. Considering the hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}_{2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, I need to compute the measure of the unit cube:

$A = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x\in [0,1], y \in[0,1], z\in[0,1]\}$

I am reasonably certain the answer is $\infty$, however in this case I would need to bound the approximating measure from below which I am unsure how to do.

Another idea I thought would be that $\cup_{k \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]} A_{k}$ is a subset of $A$ if for each $j \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ we define $A_{j} = \{(x,y,z):x\in[0,1], y\in[0,1], z = j\}$. Then if I could show each $A_{j}$ has positive measure this would prove it. However the next part of the question is to show that $A_{0}$ has positive measure so if I do it this way I would be skipping ahead a bit.

Comment: Can you show that $B = \{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : x\in [0,1], \, y\in [0,1],\, z = 0\}$ has positive $\mathcal{H}_2$-measure?

Comment: @DanielFischer I think a way to show this would be that if the Hausdorff measure was $0$, this would imply the lebesgue measure was $0$ and then I could show this to be untrue. However, I only know the Hausdorff measure is a scaling of the lebesgue measure through my own study, it is not in our lectures notes so I am unsure if I could use this fact. Unfortunately I am not sure of another way I could show this.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the $\mathcal H^2$ measure is finite: that is, there is $M<\infty$ such that for every $\delta>0$ the cube can be covered by  family of sets $E_j$ such that $\operatorname{diam}E_j<\delta$ and $\sum_j (\operatorname{diam}E_j)^2\le M$.

The set $E_j$ is contained in a ball of radius $\operatorname{diam}E_j$. The three-dimensional Lebesgue measure of this ball is 
$$\frac{4\pi}{3}(\operatorname{diam}E_j)^3\le \frac{4\pi \delta}{3} (\operatorname{diam}E_j)^2$$
Summing over $j$  leads to a contradiction.

Comment: How do you know the sum on the LHS sums to infinity, could we not have a situation where $diam E_{j} \rightarrow 0$ and the sum is finite?

Comment: Actually I guess you could say something like let $E'_{j}$ be such that $E'_{j} \supset E_{j}$ and $diam E'_{j} = max\{diam E_j, \frac{\delta}{2}\}$ and then sum $E'_{j}$

Comment: The sum of the Lebesgue measures of $E_j$ is at least the Lebesgue measure of $A$, which I assume known to be $1$. On the other hand, $\delta$ can be arbitrarily small. This is where the contradiction comes from.

Comment: Okay I get it now, thank you!